# Notification Icon not appearing on React-native expo sdk 38 project

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, expo-notifications

I'm having a serious issue using Expo Notifications on SDK 38.0.0. My notification icon does not appear on Android either IOS like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKhcg.jpg. When I remove the flag: "useNextNotificationsApi": true from app.json, my icon appears on Android but, the listener to receive the notification doesn't work anymore. My listener is:

```
const notificationListener = useRef<Subscription>();
notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(notification => {
            // setNotification(notification);
            console.log(TAG,'::addNotificationReceivedListener:',notification)
            notification.request.content.
        });
```

I'm using react-native with Typescript, and expo SDK 38.0.0, react-native: 0.62.2
expo-notifications:"^0.5.0",